# Enable/Disable stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-2012-web

I am working with a large group of stored procedures (~300) in SQL Server 2012 Web Edition and I need to enable/disable some of the stored procedures at various times.

Is there a way to create a sub-folder under "Programmability" in SQL Server Management Studio to place inactive stored procedures in? If not, is there an option to enable/disable a specific stored procedure without removing it from the database? Since I frequently need to enable/disable I would rather not remove the procedure and then re-script it when it is needed?

Comment: Is it just that you want them out of the way, or do you want them to be impossible to execute?

Comment: More just "out of the way" yet easily restorable. Like if I could create a folder that said "disabled".

Answer (score 4):

Create those stored procedure in a separate schema (use `CREATE SCHEMA`) and then GRANT or REVOKE execution right on all stored procedures in that schema for the users in charge.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, you can have contract in naming for example `spTest` is enables and `spTest_Disabled` is the same one which is disabled, so you can write another storedprocedue with this sugnature `spChangeSpStatus(spName,state)` this sp uses `sp_rename` to rename the procedure to new one,(I mean adding `_disabled` to its name or remove `_disabled` form the name)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a subfolder, but can create another schema. Name it whatever you like (say `inactive`) and set permissions on it appropriately.

Then write a script to move objects from the working schema (say `dbo`) to `inactive`:

```
alter schema inactive transfer dbo.proc
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an inexpensive tool called [SQLTreeo](http://www.sqltreeo.com/wp/) that allows you to create folders in the Object Explorer. If I remember correctly, there are two modes of operation, one that allows each user with the tool to have their individual folder structure, and another that imposes a common folder structure appear on all machines that have SQLTreeo installed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table to manage your SP, and in each SP just add an IF that always ask for the table created dbo.ManagerSP if that sp is Active=true, if true the SP runs,,,if not,,,not runs,,

And with that for control all your SP just need run an UPDATE of active status in dbo.ManagerSP